# how to populate combobox from query result?

Tags: php, combobox

i make a php page in which i get the result from database i want to populate combobox from query result how i do this?here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h1>Compare Events</h1>
<select id="mode" name="mode">
</select>
</form>
<?php
$link = connectToDB();
$strQuery="SELECT event_name from events";
    $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());
    $ors = mysql_fetch_array($result);        
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$link = connectToDB();
$strQuery="SELECT event_name from events";
    $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<form action="" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h1>Compare Events</h1>
<select id="mode" name="mode">
<?php  while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$ors['event_name'] .'" >' . $ors['event_name'] . '</option>';
        }        
 ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: If the value is the same as the text displayed in the option, you don't need to specify the value. It populates automatically.

Comment: @Styphon i did not know that. Will try it. I thought you missed it.

Comment: Also, in your example you missed the quotation marks in `value=""`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h1>Compare Events</h1>
<select id="mode" name="mode">
<?php
$link = connectToDB();
$strQuery="SELECT event_name from events";
    $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());
    while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option>' . $ors['event_name'] . '</option>';
            }        
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Notice how I moved your query inside your select so when it echo's the options they output between the opening and closing tags of your select box.

I'd also advise you stop using `mysql_*` statements, it's been depreciated (meaning that it will be removed from PHP soon). You can use [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) quite easily, it's very similar, or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as alternatives.